# Flutter: How do I change main.dart(entry point) to some other page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

> - I started working on the "home page" of the application in main.dart.
> - Then I created "Login.dart" page, and now I want my application to start with "Login.dart" page.

I am newbie in Flutter.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `-t` parameter does that which is supported by various commands (run, build, ...)

```
flutter run -t lib/my_other_main.dart
```

Comment: Thank You for your response, it was helpful. but it is working only until I debug my app again. As I debug, it starts with "main.dart" instead of "Login.dart".

Comment: You need to add the parameter to the run config if you use Android Studio/IntellyJ. I don't know about VSCode.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I found this great article that helped me with VSCode -> https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-multiple-targets-in-flutter-apps-vs-code-android-studio-efe7e588e0cd

Answer (score 26):

If you want to build your release app with the main entrypoint in a file other than lib/config/main_production.dart, you have to do so like this:

```
flutter build apk -t lib/config/main_production.dart
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - how to change it for a built application running on a device.

Answer (score 25):

In **Android Studio**, You can change your Dart entry point from `Edit configurations`.

Go to: `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Dart entrypoint`

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only way I could get to 'Edit Configurations...', was to click on the 'Run' first.

Comment: You have to add void main() => runApp(MyApp()); on the top of your class name after modifying the configuration

Comment: Not working for me and I am not sure why. Tried everything.

Answer (score 19):

### Follow these pictures:

[image: Click on run button]

[image: Create a lounch json file]

[image: Click on Dart&Flutter]

### be sure you write the right path:

hint: ("lib/start.dart") just example.

[image: Change entrypoint]

### image(5) to test your new entrypoint:

[image: Test your new entrypoint]

Answer (score 9):

`flutter run -t lib/main_admin.dart` the `t` stands for target, the default of which is lib/main.dart.  If you don't specify the -t you will go to lib/main.dart

you can also pass in `--flavor` to the flutter run command if you would like to load a different flavour for your same entry point - ie production, dev & test

Answer (score 7):

In your `main.dart` you can specify the first screen that your app opens to:

```dart
runApp(new MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: //theme
  title: "Title",
  home: new Login(), //Here you can specify the screen the app starts on.
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    //routes
  },
));
```

I'm not sure if this is any better than Günter's answer, but mine will mean you don't have to always specify the file name when building or running.

Answer (score 0):

> We have a separate file for this. Please follow below steps:

1.Go to test> **widget.test.dart**
2.Change import `package:flutter_async/main.dart`
to `package:flutter_async/your_file_name.dart`

and in the class which you have defined you can use your **MyApp** (*which runapp function will take as a input*) class or you can rename Myapp class also to some other class from widget.testfile as a first screen for your app.