# Flutter crashes and gives weird message

Tags: flutter

When I try to run debug mode on android it prints this:

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A3003 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterActivity( 1805): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 1805): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 1805): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
```

After it prints Built...app-debug.apk for a moment I can see the screen blinking, like if it was going to open the app and than it crashes and stays like this forever.

Flutter doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418], locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (8 weeks ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • ONEPLUS A3003 • 73c2cc6e • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: You are not going to get much help with your question, you have included info messages that include no errors, according to the logging you have shared everything is fine.

Comment: That's why I'm in such a difficulty, it looks fine but it doesn't run the app

Comment: You will have to check your simulator, use a new Android simulator, if you are using Mac OS try an iOS simulator. Start new simple flutter project with little code see if that runs. Try using Visual Code instead of Android Studio, which I recommend anyways unless you have native Android components you are integrating.

Comment: It actually runs on a new project, it might be a project problem, but when I try to run my project it doesn't even trigger the main, it stops before (Tried with breakpoints). It might be some dependencies problem, but I have no idea how to isolate it

Comment: By the way, till yesterday it worked. Today I updated flutter and a couple of deps, and it stopped working. Now I put everything back and it still doesn't work :)

Comment: Like you said it runs on a new project, did you try a new simulator, you have to completely clear Android simulators sometimes, just fully delete

Answer (score 0):

I have various issue after flutter upgrade, ever try command below ?

> flutter clean

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

If you are never triggering main.dart, this is most likely due to either:

1. Changing the project settings for the project root or
2. Moving main.dart file somewhere other than the root folder.

Please check that your main.dart is located in the folder that your project settings specifies. See this:

[Flutter : How do i change main.dart(entry point) to some other page in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510244/flutter-how-do-i-change-main-dartentry-point-to-some-other-page-in-flutter)

If it not not either of these issues, we would need you to post more code that could help with pinpointing the issue.