# What's the first page (Dart file) will run in Flutter App when I launch

Tags: flutter

I programmed a flutter app that contains multiple dart files. But how apk package decide, which dart file to run first when app launch on the phone? What I mean is I want to set a dart file as the main/home page of my application and I want to run it first. How I set it up?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510244/flutter-how-do-i-change-main-dartentry-point-to-some-other-page-in-flutter).

Comment: read carefully output of `flutter build apk -h` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like this on **main.dart** file

```
main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: appThemeData(),
      title: 'YOUR_APP_NAME',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => LoginPage(),
        '/mainMenu': (context) => MainMenu(),
        '/splash': (context) => SplashScreen(),

      },

    );
  }
}
```