# Getting error like "Target file "lib\main.dart" not found." whlie building APK in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

When i do Build -> Flutter -> Build APK in android studio for flutter application, i get the error like "Target file "lib\main.dart" not found.", although i'm able to run application because i have changed the test/widget_test.dart file.

I have changed the main file to routes.dart file which is in the lib folder,
so how to solve this error?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

When i run command "flutter build apk --target=lib/routes.dart", I get error like this :

[image]

Comment: did you try invalidate and restart ?

Comment: Yes i have but still same issue @ParthPitroda

Comment: see this once  :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56477668/8388068

Answer (score 3):

The default entry point is main.dart Since there is no main.dart file in your /lib directory you have to specify the entry point.
Run the command to build with target option:

```
flutter build apk --target=lib/routes.dart
```

Comment: I have updated my post above please check it @SeverinKlug

Comment: You have another error in your project. Your initial problem is solved: "lib\main.dart" not found". The next error message is pretty much saying what went wrong. Update your gradle to 1.3.10 or higher

Comment: Thanks the earlier problem is solved now please see if you can help with this also

Comment: This also happens you open your Flutter project on Android Studio (the android folder in the project), while the `main.dart` file is not in `lib` folder