# Target file "lib\main.dart" not found. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, program-entry-point

Even I have the file in lib/ folder flutter gives me error

Here is my file

[image: main dart location]
C:\SRC\flutter\packages\flutter_tools>flutter run
Target file "lib\main.dart" not found.

Edit:

here is my configuration

[image]

I have looked to this topic
[Getting error like "Target file "lib\main.dart" not found." whlie building APK in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110114/getting-error-like-target-file-lib-main-dart-not-found-whlie-building-apk-i)

But this situation is different from mine.

Answer (score 4):

**Reason:**
This is the error because of the main execution starts searching main file, but can't find it.
**Solution:**
Go to Edit Configurations...
[image]
Set here main.dart file as dart entry point here and save it...
[image]
**Another Solution**
Run following command
`flutter run -t lib/main.dart`

Comment: I added my configuration. I think it is correct. I recreated my project. I copied my project files. After that error is gone. But I do not understand the error.

Comment: This mostly occurs when you open a new project instead import it to IDE.